# Check ArrayList if null

Tags: android, arraylist, singleton

I have a problem in my Android program. I created an arrayList in a Singleton class. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out why my conditions won't work checking if the array is null or its length is equal to 0.

My Singleton Class:

```
public class Controller{

    private static final String TAG = "check product in list: ";
    private static Controller ourInstance = null;

    public ArrayList<Item> myProducts = new ArrayList<>();



    private Controller() {
    }

    public static Controller getInstance() {

        if ( ourInstance == null){
            ourInstance = new Controller();
        }
        return ourInstance;
    }
}
```

Item Activity --> Item Class I have written the following test codes and they all don't work:

Checking if empty:

```
if ( Controller.getInstance().myProducts.isEmpty() ){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Checking with length:

```
if ( Controller.getInstance().myProducts.toString().length() == 0 ){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Checking with size -- length

```
if ( Controller.getInstance().myProducts.size() == 0 ){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Checking if null:

```
if ( Controller.getInstance().myProducts.toString == null ){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I did not add anything into the list. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Controller.getInstance().myProducts.toString().length() remove toString() in this line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list will never be null because you're initializing it when you're declaring the variable. Make sure your code is fully Encapsulated. Make your member variable private and then create setter and getter to modify and obtain value respectively, it's considered to be a good practice. Therefore for your case, your code should look like something below.

```
public class Controller{

    private static final String TAG = "check product in list: ";
    private static Controller ourInstance = null;
    private ArrayList<Item> myProducts = new ArrayList<>();


    // Add comment for the reason of using private constructor.
    private Controller() {
    }

    public static Controller getInstance() {

        if ( ourInstance == null){
            ourInstance = new Controller();
        }
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public List<Item> getProducts(){
        return this.myProducts;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Item> products){
        if (products == null || products.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }

        // Clear the list
        this.myProducts.clear();

        // Add all items to the list
        this.myProducts.addAll(products)
   }
}
```

Now Since you're using a singleton pattern, which means that this class will only be created once during the application cycle. And it is available to be called anywhere from you project like below.

Example 01: Adding items to the list.

```
Controller.getInstance().setProducts(products);
```

Example 02: Reading the products list.

```
List<Item> products = Controller.getInstance().getProducts();
if(products != null && products.isEmpty()){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Products list is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use condition `if ( Controller.getInstance().myProducts.toString().length() == 0 )` in your code .

- When you use `toString` method , it will return type like this `"[]"`.
- And length was not the list's item sum,it was `String` 's length

And the resource of List's `isEmpty` method .

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}
```

So we just use `size` method .

And `myProducts` is Initialized in `Controller` ,So it will be not null .

You can try

```
// 1. size is 0
    if(Controller.getInstance().myProducts.size() == 0){
    // do something here when the list's lenght is 0
} else {
    // do something here when the list's lenght is not 0
}
```

Comment: But why Controller.getInstance().myProducts.isEmpty() is not working ?

Comment: `public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }` is check the size of list.And i add it .

Comment: Yes, I will remove it .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

```
public ArrayList<Item> myProducts = null;
public Controller() 
  {
    myProducts = new ArrayList<Item>();
  }

public ArrayList<Item> getLIST() 
  {
     return this.myProducts ;
  }
```

Now check [**`size()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size())

> The java.util.ArrayList.size() method returns the number of elements
>   in this list i.e the size of the list.

```
if(Controller.getInstance().getLIST().size()==0)
{ 
 // TOAST
}
```

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya Edited.

Comment: But in above code Controller.getInstance().myProducts.isEmpty() is perfect, Why isEmpty() method not working ?

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya need to check. But checking `size` is safe.

Comment: But if your ArrayList is public then you don't create getter or setter method, You can directly access list

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya In my code need to add `SET` method like `Tonny Baya's` code.

Comment: Make your member variable private and then create setter and getter to modify and obtain value respectively